# Is there some SO user account level where downvoting don't costs reps?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, downvotes, stack-exchange

I am SO user from couple of years. Initially, when I was downvoting some answer, as far as I remember, 2 reps were getting deducted from my account. Now, when I downvote some answer, it costs me 1 rep.

I would like to know whether there is some SO user account level after reaching which I will not get charged for downvoting answers, in terms of reps?

Comment: Downvoting another answer has always cost 1 point. This is the same for all reputation levels.

Comment: Someone else downvoting _your_ question or answer does still cost you 2 rep.  Downvoting a _question_ costs no rep (-1 for answers) but that has been the policy for around 4 years.

Comment: May be I don't remember properly.  Thanks for responses to all.

Comment: @RAJ Are you thinking of you *being* downvoted by someone else?

Comment: No  @james .. I was asking when I downvote someone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any answer that is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/175248) does not transfer rep in any way, either via downvotes or upvotes on it.

At all other times, downvoting an answer will cost reputation.  It's also [been the same -1 reputation value](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) for a while, so you were likely downvoting multiple things at once.